# List of blue counterspells that can be played for free?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I looked around on the internet for a list of blue counterspells in Magic: the Gathering that can be played for no mana. (Alternative costs or a mana cost *later* is fine.) Does anyone have a list or know where to find a list?

Comment: No mana _ever,_ or just no mana _right now?_ That would affect whether things like [Pact of Negation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370354) appear on the list.

Comment: Ones that can be played for no mana right now.

Comment: Does it have to be a spell?  counterbalance is an enchantment that costs zero mana (once it's on the battlefield) to counter spells.  There are several other permanents that can be used to counter spells.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 8 [Blue counterspells that can be cast for alternate costs](https://scryfall.com/search?q=%28o%3A%22rather+than+pay+%7E%27s+mana+cost%22+or+o%3A%22you+may+cast+this+spell+without+paying+its+mana+cost%22%29+o%3Acounter+c%3Au&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name):

- [Admiral's Order](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Admiral%27s%20Order) (The alternate cost still costs {U})
- [Daze](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Daze)
- [Disrupting Shoal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Disrupting%20Shoal)
- [Fierce Guardianship](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fierce%20Guardianship)
- [Foil](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Foil)
- [Force of Negation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Force%20of%20Negation)
- [Force of Will](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Force%20of%20Will)
- [Thwart](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thwart)

I found these with the following search on [Scryfall](https://scryfall.com/):

> (o:"rather than pay ~'s mana cost" or o:"you may cast this spell without paying its mana cost") o:counter c:u

This searches for spells with alternative costs (first clause) with "counter" in the text (second clause) that are blue (third clause).

In addition, [Mental Misstep](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mental%20Misstep) only costs {UP}, so you can pay life instead of mana.

If you also want to count spells with mana that needs to be paid later, [Pact of Negation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pact%20of%20Negation) has a mana cost of {0}, but it also says

> At the beginning of your next upkeep, pay {3}{U}{U}. If you don't, you lose the game.

Besides that, there are [3 spells](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3Atarget+o%3Aspell+-o%3Acounter+o%3A%22rather+than+pay+%7E%27s+mana+cost%22+c%3Au) that can be used to *effectively* counter a spell that can be cast without paying any mana:

- [Commandeer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Commandeer) lets you take control of a spell and change its targets. You can choose a target that is (more) beneficial to you, or, if the other spell is a counterspell, you can redirect it to target Commandeer so that it is countered for having an illegal target after Commandeer leaves the stack.
- [Mindbreak Trap](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mindbreak%20Trap) lets you exile any number of spells, but you can only cast it for free if your opponent has cast at least 3 spells this turn.
- [Misdirection](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Misdirection) also lets you choose new targets for a spell. Of course, it is only useful for dealing with targeted spells, and you can use it to deal with counterspells the same way you can use Commandeer.

Comment: [Fierce Guardianship](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=484882) can be added to the list if you're playing Commander.

Comment: I added that. I missed it because it uses a different alternate cost wording.

Comment: Yeah, wasn't sure where you wanted to add it because your description below the list is now slightly incorrect. Also maybe Pact of Negation as mentioned in comments? (Oh, you updated that as well!)

Comment: Depending on how you read it, the description is still right. The whole parenthesized expression searches for spells with alternative costs, it just now includes two different wordings for them. Pact of Negation was there the whole time. The only change I made today was to expand the list at the beginning.